# how do I add a clicktag in JS to a banner done with flash cc2014 html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, flash-cc, clicktag

I made a banner using flashcc2014 using the html5 canvas. I just don't know how to add the normal clicktag banners need in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard click tag in your html5 banner would be:

```
window.open(clickTag, "_blank");
```

The value for clickTag will be a string provided by the media company trafficking your ad, just as it would be for a Flash banner.